# libGDX project on mac in IntelliJ android location error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, libgdx

I created new libGDX project (Android/iOS/Desktop) and I tried running it but I got this error (I am using Java 1.8 and Android API 26).

```
 Error:Internal error: (java.lang.ClassNotFoundException) com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation$AndroidLocationException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidTarget(AndroidJpsUtil.java:404)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.android.AndroidJpsUtil.getAndroidPlatform(AndroidJpsUtil.java:480)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.android.builder.AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.computeRootDescriptors(AndroidPreDexBuildTarget.java:110)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.addRoots(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:72)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.builders.impl.BuildRootIndexImpl.<init>(BuildRootIndexImpl.java:62)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:84)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:267)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler.lambda$channelRead0$0(BuildMain.java:236)
        at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl.lambda$executeOnPooledThread$0(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:42)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: WARNING - OFFTOPIC - really happy to see you on stackoveflow giuseppe...

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `IntelliJ IDEA` are you using?
Try to upgrade to `IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.2`

More info: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176144

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2 July

Comment: So, upgrade to 2017.2.2

Comment: Fix it but now a i have this error
Error:Android Pre Dex: [gdx-1.9.6.jar] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.dx.command.DxConsole

Comment: Did you tried to clean and rebuild your project? Also please add you configuration file to the question (I'm not sure how this works in `IntelliJ IDEA`, but in `Android Studio` this is `build.gradle` file)